# Pretty output in GHCI: no colours shown

Tags: shell, haskell

Using [this method to get a pretty GHCI colours](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/144biy/pretty_output_in_ghci_howto_in_comments/), I am not getting any colours whatsoever.  However, my terminal is a urxvt with 256 colours enabled and TERM is `xterm-256color`.  Any idea what I could have missed?

My ~/.ghci reads:

```
import qualified IPPrint
import qualified Language.Haskell.HsColour as HsColour
import qualified Language.Haskell.HsColour.Colourise as HsColour
import qualified Language.Haskell.HsColour.Output as HsColour

let myColourPrefs = HsColour.defaultColourPrefs { HsColour.conid = [HsColour.Foreground HsColour.Yellow, HsColour.Bold], HsColour.conop = [HsColour.Foreground HsColour.Yellow], HsColour.string = [HsColour.Foreground HsColour.Green], HsColour.char = [HsColour.Foreground HsColour.Cyan], HsColour.number = [HsColour.Foreground HsColour.Red, HsColour.Bold], HsColour.layout = [HsColour.Foreground HsColour.White], HsColour.keyglyph = [HsColour.Foreground HsColour.White] }

let myPrint = putStrLn . HsColour.hscolour (HsColour.TTYg HsColour.XTerm256Compatible) myColourPrefs False False "" False . IPPrint.pshow

:set -interactive-print=myPrint
:set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction
:set prompt "λ "
```

The prompt should look like this: 
[image: haskell ghci colour prompt]

Comment: What version of `ghci` do you have?  What happens if you replace the function with something that prints some strong? Is it executed?

Comment: @Mikel: `The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.4.1` and replacing myPrint does not seem to call it at all -- I just changed it to `let myPrint = putStrLn "ook"`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need GHCI version >= 7.6.1 for the `-interactive-print` option.

[Reddit: Pretty Output in GHCi (HOWTO in comments)](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/144biy/pretty_output_in_ghci_howto_in_comments/)

> I was prettying up my GHCi and found a new flag in GHC 7.6 (-interactive-print)

[[GHC] #5461](http://www.haskell.org/pipermail/glasgow-haskell-bugs/2012-June/038709.html)

> Milestone:  7.6.1

Comment: Has anybody this working with recent `ghci` versions? Not working for me with 7.10.2

Answer (score 1):

You need to place `:set -XNoMonomorphismRestriction` before `let myPrint = ...`, tested using GHCi 7.6.3.

Alternatively, without -XNoMonomorphismRestriction:

```
let myPrint :: (Show a) => a -> IO (); myPrint = putStrLn . HsColour.hscolour (HsColour.TTYg HsColour.XTerm256Compatible) myColourPrefs False False "" False . IPPrint.pshow
```

Full .ghci(slight modification of the solution in the original Reddit post): http://pastebin.com/ry9JyDd9